# Writing a two-form as a wedge product

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Suppose a differential two-form $\Omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by  $\Omega_p(x, y)=p_2(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)$.

> Then using coordinates $(p_1, p_2)$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, this reads
>   $$\Omega_p=\frac{1}{p_2}dp_1\wedge dp_2.$$

I don't understand why $p_2$ goes in the denominator when we use the wedge product. Can someone explain this to me please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write the tangent vectors $(r, s)_{\mathfrak{g}^*}(\mu)$ and $(u, v)_{\mathfrak{g}^*}(\mu)$ in terms of basis vectors for the tangent space of the orbit at $\mu$.

Apply $d\alpha\wedge d\beta$ to the pair of these tangent vectors and you will see that you get $\beta^2(rv-su)$.

(This is an exercise in your book at the end of the section.)

Answer (score 0):

You sure that's it? Notice: $$(dp_1 \wedge dp_2)_{{\bf p}}({\bf x},{\bf y}) = \begin{vmatrix} (dp_1)_{{\bf p}}({\bf x}) & (dp_1)_{{\bf p}}({\bf y}) \\ (dp_2)_{{\bf p}}({\bf x}) & (dp_2)_{{\bf p}}({\bf y}) \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \end{vmatrix} = \frac{1}{p_2}p_2(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1),$$hence $(dp_1 \wedge dp_2)_{{\bf p}}({\bf x},{\bf y}) = \frac{1}{p_2} \Omega_{{\bf p}}({\bf x},{\bf y})$.

Comment: Please see page 460 of this book. http://books.google.pl/books?id=I2gH9ZIs-3AC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=458&f=false

Comment: I am not so familiar with Lie Groups, etc, so I don't feel so secure to give you a definite explanation. But to check this formula, I would compute both sides in the canonical basis of the tangent space, and see that they coincide. Then they would be equal, by linearity.

Comment: My calculation is the same as yours @Ivo. But I don't see why it doesn't agree with what is in the book.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with these $\mu$ and $\frak g$, some property or definition about these objects, that changes something in the middle of the calculation. On the other hand, apart from this context, I'm sure that the calculations we've done only with the $dp_i$ and $\Omega$ are correct.